# Manage confidential information in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, security, hash

I have a table in my php that shows the data of a table in my database: username, email, etc. and I have also added an option to delete. The delete option works correctly and also shows a confirmation message with a necessary password before deleting.

I have the passwords saved in a table in the database but not encrypted.

The problem is that if a user explores the content of the page they can see what’s the password, so anyone can be able to delete data from the database. Therefore, a more or less skilled user can easily explore that content.

What can I do to prevent this from happening? Should I copy the same JavaScript code in another script and delete it from index.php? For more security, I tried to use a hash on the same index.php page but you can also see what the password is.

This is my code:

index.php

```
<table id="professorsRegistered" border="1px">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="3"><h2>Users</h2></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th> Name </th>
        <th> Email </th>
        <th> Delete </th>
    </tr>

<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users"; /*Select from table name: users*/
$result = $conn->query($sql); /*Check connection*/

if ($result->num_rows==0){

    echo "No users";
}else{
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>".$row["username"]."</td><td>".$row["email"]."</td><td><a class='eliminate' onClick=\"getPass(".$row['id'].");\">X</a></td></tr>";
    }
}

?>
</table>


<?php
        $sql = "SELECT password FROM passwords WHERE passwords_id = '1';"; /*Select from table name: passwords*/
        $result = $conn->query($sql); /*Check connection*/
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $password = $row["password"];
        $hash = sha1($password);
        /*echo "<p>".$hash."</p>";*/
        ?>


<script type = "text/javascript">
    function getPass(user) {
        var securePass = "<?php echo $password ?>";
        var pass = prompt("Introduce password to delete: ", "Password");
        if (pass!=securePass) {
            return confirm('Incorrect Password');
        }
        else if (pass==securePass) {
            window.location='delete.php?id='+user;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Delete.php

```
<?php
include('Conexion.php'); // Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$id = $_GET['id']; // $id is defined

mysqli_query($conn,"DELETE FROM users WHERE id='".$id."'");
mysqli_close($conn);
header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

Comment: none of the variations offer any security. Find a different way to handle the athorization to delete. Like: store (or "calculate") on the server what user may do what kind of actions, f.e. have an "admin" flag for users who may do so. Then - of course - on every request to the server check for logged in user (via authtoken, session, etc)

Comment: also make sure to prepare your sql statements! Right now I could easily delete _all_ users.

Comment: I think your bigger problem is that anyone can delete everything in your database. What happens if someone calls `delete.php?id=1%27+OR+%271%27%3D%271` Bye bye database table. Look into prepared statements.

Comment: I agree with @Jeff & @Miken - nothing about this seems secure if merely browsing the page source can reveal weaknesses. The sql in the `delete.php` script is vulnerable to firstly sql injection and potentially for a user to delete many, many users simply by changing the ID. Do NOT use `sha1`, use password hashing to store passwords.

Answer (score 2):

To make this more secure you should look at doing the following:

1. Ensure that the credentials are validated in the server-side code (PHP), not the client side code.  As malicious user can very easily either edit the JavaScript or post data directly to your server and totally bypass your code.
2. Passwords should be hashed with a appropriate password hashing algorithm.  SHA1 is not a good algorithm for password hashing as it is too fast, which makes brute force and dictionary attacks easier.  A better choice would be something like bcrypt or pbkdf2 these are much slower making the above attacks much more difficult.  You should also salt your password.  This means just adding some randomness to the password before it is hashed.  This will help prevent an attack known as a rainbow table attack in which an attacker uses a set of pre-hashed values and corresponding plain text to speed up the brute force process.
3. Do not build SQL query stings by string contactination as this leaves your application vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. If a malicious user was to send up 1' OR 1=1 -- as the id parameter then all the users would be deleted, this technique could also be used dump all of the data from the database or even delete the database altogether. Look in to using parameterized queries instead.

Luckily there is already loads of information on how to do this the right way. I would recommend looking at the OWASP website which has plenty of examples.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things which are very wrong about this design. You need to fix them.

1. Do not store cleartext passwords in your database. Hash passwords using a password hash function (like PHP's `password_hash()` or `sodium_crypto_pwhash()`) **before** storing them in the database. (SHA1 is not a password hash, and should not be used for this purpose.)
2. Do not construct SQL queries with string interpolation or concatenation. You're already using PDO, so you can easily use parameter placeholders to prevent SQL injection.
3. Do not expose password hashes to the browser in any form. If you need to verify a password, submit it to the server as part of the request to perform a password-protected action, so that a user cannot bypass the password check by typing a URL in manually.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to fix what you answered me. Could I change the password of the database by: UPDATE passwords SET password = SHA ('hello') WHERE passwords_id = '1'; Is it a good option for security?

Comment: No. As I said in my answer: SHA1 is not a password hash, and should not be used for this purpose.